# Java: What is the best way to add odd numbers in order to get 1 4 9 16 as output

Tags: java, computer-science-theory

I know how to display the odd numbers, but can't figure out how to display the sum of odd numbers in order to get `1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100` output
the idea is to use

- 1=1
- 1+3=4
- 4+5=9
- and so on

The idea is to avoid multiplication. (I know it would be the easiest solution.)

What I have so far is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++){

             if( i % 2 != 0){
                     System.out.print(i + " ");
             }
     }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You have the loop. All you are missing is the addition :

```
 int num = 0;
 for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
     if( i % 2 != 0) {
         num = num + i;
         System.out.print(num + " ");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to avoid multiplication, then replacing that with division (or rather remainder) seems meaningless.

What you want is to use the `+=` operator:

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i += 2) {
    num += i;
    System.out.print(num + " ");
}
```

**Output**

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 400 441 484 529 576 625 676 729 784 841 900 961 1024 1089 1156 1225 1296 1369 1444 1521 1600 1681 1764 1849 1936 2025 2116 2209 2304 2401 2500
```

Note: This is just an optimized version of the [answer by Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34848705/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

As they are squares: The difference between two squares is always its base two times minus 1:

```
 int num = 0;
 for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
         num += i+i-1;
         System.out.print(i + " ");
 }
```